# Do central pattern generators control musical performance?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, motor

Are the sometimes very fast and complicated rhythmic movements and often long lasting patterns a musician performs while playing a piece of music generated by [central pattern generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_pattern_generator) (in the sense of Wikipedia)?

I ask because I am astonished that intricate and fast rhythmic patterns are not mentioned in the article, but only basal and rather slow motions like locomotion, respiration, swallowing. Is it because other systems are responsible for the fast and complicated patterns observed in musical high-performance than central pattern generators? If so: which ones?

(Note, that heart beat isn't mentioned, neither. What does this mean?)

Comment: Related: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/13694/4397